# HLS Event Stream from Azure Blob Storage

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, video.js, http-live-streaming, m3u8

Alright, so I encode videos of around 30 seconds with ffmpeg, the following flags:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i \"{filename}\"  -f hls -hls_segment_type fmp4 -hls_flags single_file -hls_time 5 -g 1 \"{outname}.m3u8\"
```

This generates a single playlist with an m4s and m3u8 file:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:7
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:5
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-MAP:URI="1e02982a-c455-40f5-8229-1033a640c91c-0.mp4.m4s",BYTERANGE="818@0"
#EXTINF:4.781911,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1398720@5953584
1e02982a-c455-40f5-8229-1033a640c91c-0.mp4.m4s
#EXTINF:5.063200,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1490276@7352304
1e02982a-c455-40f5-8229-1033a640c91c-0.mp4.m4s
#EXTINF:5.063200,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1484824@8842580
1e02982a-c455-40f5-8229-1033a640c91c-0.mp4.m4s
#EXTINF:5.063200,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1468656@10327404
1e02982a-c455-40f5-8229-1033a640c91c-0.mp4.m4s
#EXTINF:1.969022,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:576408@11796060
1e02982a-c455-40f5-8229-1033a640c91c-0.mp4.m4s
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

I take this playlist and append several others that are just the same as they come adding a DIscontinuity tag and between each of them and removing unneeded tags. While doing this I replace the filenames with a working SAS URL for the actual files.

Which results in files of the following type:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:EVENT
#EXT-X-VERSION:7
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-INDEPENDENT-SEGMENTS
#EXT-X-MAP:URI="https://vsatstreams.blob.core.windows.net/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/1-frag.m4s?sv=2018-03-28&sr=b&sig=el%2F529BGb4Xjeetiv9kxaHAxGYC%2BwogSYgvCivq1tlc%3D&st=2019-01-10T05%3A09%3A13Z&se=2021-01-10T05%3A14%3A13Z&sp=rw",BYTERANGE="818@0"
#EXTINF:4.654771,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1474761@4854677
https://vsatstreams.blob.core.windows.net/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/1-frag.m4s?sv=2018-03-28&sr=b&sig=el%2F529BGb4Xjeetiv9kxaHAxGYC%2BwogSYgvCivq1tlc%3D&st=2019-01-10T05%3A09%3A13Z&se=2021-01-10T05%3A14%3A13Z&sp=rw
#EXTINF:5.430566,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1716825@6329438
https://vsatstreams.blob.core.windows.net/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/1-frag.m4s?sv=2018-03-28&sr=b&sig=el%2F529BGb4Xjeetiv9kxaHAxGYC%2BwogSYgvCivq1tlc%3D&st=2019-01-10T05%3A09%3A13Z&se=2021-01-10T05%3A14%3A13Z&sp=rw
#EXTINF:4.654771,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1479725@8046263
https://vsatstreams.blob.core.windows.net/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/1-frag.m4s?sv=2018-03-28&sr=b&sig=el%2F529BGb4Xjeetiv9kxaHAxGYC%2BwogSYgvCivq1tlc%3D&st=2019-01-10T05%3A09%3A13Z&se=2021-01-10T05%3A14%3A13Z&sp=rw
#EXTINF:5.430566,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1710125@9525988
https://vsatstreams.blob.core.windows.net/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/1-frag.m4s?sv=2018-03-28&sr=b&sig=el%2F529BGb4Xjeetiv9kxaHAxGYC%2BwogSYgvCivq1tlc%3D&st=2019-01-10T05%3A09%3A13Z&se=2021-01-10T05%3A14%3A13Z&sp=rw
#EXTINF:3.103181,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:200@11236113
https://vsatstreams.blob.core.windows.net/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/1-frag.m4s?sv=2018-03-28&sr=b&sig=el%2F529BGb4Xjeetiv9kxaHAxGYC%2BwogSYgvCivq1tlc%3D&st=2019-01-10T05%3A09%3A13Z&se=2021-01-10T05%3A14%3A13Z&sp=rw
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXT-X-MAP:URI="https://vsatstreams.blob.core.windows.net/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/2-frag.m4s?sv=2018-03-28&sr=b&sig=s3s3R1sjE6lZRgfmaYdOkOGCr7BYkOrygBy%2F90crwvM%3D&st=2019-01-10T05%3A09%3A53Z&se=2021-01-10T05%3A14%3A53Z&sp=rw",BYTERANGE="819@0"
#EXTINF:4.897959,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1506220@6184008
https://vsatstreams.blob.core.windows.net/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/2-frag.m4s?sv=2018-03-28&sr=b&sig=s3s3R1sjE6lZRgfmaYdOkOGCr7BYkOrygBy%2F90crwvM%3D&st=2019-01-10T05%3A09%3A53Z&se=2021-01-10T05%3A14%3A53Z&sp=rw
#EXTINF:4.897959,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1496289@7690228
https://vsatstreams.blob.core.windows.net/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/2-frag.m4s?sv=2018-03-28&sr=b&sig=s3s3R1sjE6lZRgfmaYdOkOGCr7BYkOrygBy%2F90crwvM%3D&st=2019-01-10T05%3A09%3A53Z&se=2021-01-10T05%3A14%3A53Z&sp=rw
#EXTINF:4.897959,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1516854@9186517
https://vsatstreams.blob.core.windows.net/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/2-frag.m4s?sv=2018-03-28&sr=b&sig=s3s3R1sjE6lZRgfmaYdOkOGCr7BYkOrygBy%2F90crwvM%3D&st=2019-01-10T05%3A09%3A53Z&se=2021-01-10T05%3A14%3A53Z&sp=rw
#EXTINF:4.897959,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1492617@10703371
https://vsatstreams.blob.core.windows.net/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/2-frag.m4s?sv=2018-03-28&sr=b&sig=s3s3R1sjE6lZRgfmaYdOkOGCr7BYkOrygBy%2F90crwvM%3D&st=2019-01-10T05%3A09%3A53Z&se=2021-01-10T05%3A14%3A53Z&sp=rw
#EXTINF:0.816327,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:219@12195988
https://vsatstreams.blob.core.windows.net/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/2-frag.m4s?sv=2018-03-28&sr=b&sig=s3s3R1sjE6lZRgfmaYdOkOGCr7BYkOrygBy%2F90crwvM%3D&st=2019-01-10T05%3A09%3A53Z&se=2021-01-10T05%3A14%3A53Z&sp=rw
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXT-X-MAP:URI="https://vsatstreams.blob.core.windows.net/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/3-frag.m4s?sv=2018-03-28&sr=b&sig=O%2B%2FQBnVcyIzn2r3T8S7xq2dic9LKW3q7p2bGSYen%2BbI%3D&st=2019-01-10T05%3A10%3A43Z&se=2021-01-10T05%3A15%3A43Z&sp=rw",BYTERANGE="820@0"
#EXTINF:5.000000,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1352781@6631869
https://vsatstreams.blob.core.windows.net/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/3-frag.m4s?sv=2018-03-28&sr=b&sig=O%2B%2FQBnVcyIzn2r3T8S7xq2dic9LKW3q7p2bGSYen%2BbI%3D&st=2019-01-10T05%3A10%3A43Z&se=2021-01-10T05%3A15%3A43Z&sp=rw
#EXTINF:5.000000,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1357320@7984650
https://vsatstreams.blob.core.windows.net/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/3-frag.m4s?sv=2018-03-28&sr=b&sig=O%2B%2FQBnVcyIzn2r3T8S7xq2dic9LKW3q7p2bGSYen%2BbI%3D&st=2019-01-10T05%3A10%3A43Z&se=2021-01-10T05%3A15%3A43Z&sp=rw
#EXTINF:5.000000,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1360645@9341970
https://vsatstreams.blob.core.windows.net/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/3-frag.m4s?sv=2018-03-28&sr=b&sig=O%2B%2FQBnVcyIzn2r3T8S7xq2dic9LKW3q7p2bGSYen%2BbI%3D&st=2019-01-10T05%3A10%3A43Z&se=2021-01-10T05%3A15%3A43Z&sp=rw
#EXTINF:5.000000,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1334946@10702615
https://vsatstreams.blob.core.windows.net/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/3-frag.m4s?sv=2018-03-28&sr=b&sig=O%2B%2FQBnVcyIzn2r3T8S7xq2dic9LKW3q7p2bGSYen%2BbI%3D&st=2019-01-10T05%3A10%3A43Z&se=2021-01-10T05%3A15%3A43Z&sp=rw
#EXTINF:5.000000,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:238@12037561
https://vsatstreams.blob.core.windows.net/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/3-frag.m4s?sv=2018-03-28&sr=b&sig=O%2B%2FQBnVcyIzn2r3T8S7xq2dic9LKW3q7p2bGSYen%2BbI%3D&st=2019-01-10T05%3A10%3A43Z&se=2021-01-10T05%3A15%3A43Z&sp=rw
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXT-X-MAP:URI="https://vsatstreams.blob.core.windows.net/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/4-frag.m4s?sv=2018-03-28&sr=b&sig=jPsSq8%2FfNzfjUx5bauJs7mkLu8w%2FYFKLaeLRBu8lPzg%3D&st=2019-01-10T05%3A11%3A25Z&se=2021-01-10T05%3A16%3A25Z&sp=rw",BYTERANGE="820@0"
#EXTINF:5.000000,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1359259@6647772
https://vsatstreams.blob.core.windows.net/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/4-frag.m4s?sv=2018-03-28&sr=b&sig=jPsSq8%2FfNzfjUx5bauJs7mkLu8w%2FYFKLaeLRBu8lPzg%3D&st=2019-01-10T05%3A11%3A25Z&se=2021-01-10T05%3A16%3A25Z&sp=rw
#EXTINF:5.000000,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1353269@8007031
https://vsatstreams.blob.core.windows.net/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/4-frag.m4s?sv=2018-03-28&sr=b&sig=jPsSq8%2FfNzfjUx5bauJs7mkLu8w%2FYFKLaeLRBu8lPzg%3D&st=2019-01-10T05%3A11%3A25Z&se=2021-01-10T05%3A16%3A25Z&sp=rw
#EXTINF:5.000000,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1359724@9360300
https://vsatstreams.blob.core.windows.net/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/4-frag.m4s?sv=2018-03-28&sr=b&sig=jPsSq8%2FfNzfjUx5bauJs7mkLu8w%2FYFKLaeLRBu8lPzg%3D&st=2019-01-10T05%3A11%3A25Z&se=2021-01-10T05%3A16%3A25Z&sp=rw
#EXTINF:5.000000,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1339437@10720024
https://vsatstreams.blob.core.windows.net/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/4-frag.m4s?sv=2018-03-28&sr=b&sig=jPsSq8%2FfNzfjUx5bauJs7mkLu8w%2FYFKLaeLRBu8lPzg%3D&st=2019-01-10T05%3A11%3A25Z&se=2021-01-10T05%3A16%3A25Z&sp=rw
#EXTINF:5.000000,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:238@12059461
https://vsatstreams.blob.core.windows.net/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/4-frag.m4s?sv=2018-03-28&sr=b&sig=jPsSq8%2FfNzfjUx5bauJs7mkLu8w%2FYFKLaeLRBu8lPzg%3D&st=2019-01-10T05%3A11%3A25Z&se=2021-01-10T05%3A16%3A25Z&sp=rw
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXT-X-MAP:URI="https://vsatstreams.blob.core.windows.net/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/4-frag.m4s?sv=2018-03-28&sr=b&sig=yfgkYvCLFjt384tsDZZ2ahVfPI4XxoCyyWepmux4rvc%3D&st=2019-01-10T05%3A12%3A12Z&se=2021-01-10T05%3A17%3A12Z&sp=rw",BYTERANGE="820@0"
#EXTINF:5.000000,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1371742@6775319
https://vsatstreams.blob.core.windows.net/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/4-frag.m4s?sv=2018-03-28&sr=b&sig=yfgkYvCLFjt384tsDZZ2ahVfPI4XxoCyyWepmux4rvc%3D&st=2019-01-10T05%3A12%3A12Z&se=2021-01-10T05%3A17%3A12Z&sp=rw
#EXTINF:5.000000,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1389742@8147061
https://vsatstreams.blob.core.windows.net/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/4-frag.m4s?sv=2018-03-28&sr=b&sig=yfgkYvCLFjt384tsDZZ2ahVfPI4XxoCyyWepmux4rvc%3D&st=2019-01-10T05%3A12%3A12Z&se=2021-01-10T05%3A17%3A12Z&sp=rw
#EXTINF:5.000000,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1377900@9536803
https://vsatstreams.blob.core.windows.net/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/4-frag.m4s?sv=2018-03-28&sr=b&sig=yfgkYvCLFjt384tsDZZ2ahVfPI4XxoCyyWepmux4rvc%3D&st=2019-01-10T05%3A12%3A12Z&se=2021-01-10T05%3A17%3A12Z&sp=rw
#EXTINF:5.000000,
```

[Link for file is here](https://vsatstreams.blob.core.windows.net/75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c/init.m3u8?sv=2018-03-28&sr=b&sig=0drc%2FiSwFuioavNbcOWdcBGv3Yx2ihoVbOseQlnwVW8%3D&st=2019-01-10T05%3A34%3A41Z&se=2021-01-10T05%3A39%3A41Z&sp=rw)

This stream does not play in chrome with video.js, and only plays in bitmovin client, but it constantly fails with buffer append/stalled errors. In firefox it plays, but without much reliability.

So what am I doing wrong in this process? I've checked the specification for HLS several times, can't see what I'm doing wrong, or what the player expects.

Please check hls.js player, with the following URL which uses the stream above to see what I'm talking about. 
[HLS.JS Demo Player With My Playlist](https://video-dev.github.io/hls.js/demo/?src=https%3A%2F%2Fvsatstreams.blob.core.windows.net%2F75888d6c-41fb-4cb0-9573-0e2ab7a6dc4c%2Finit.m3u8%3Fsv%3D2018-03-28%26sr%3Db%26sig%3D0drc%252FiSwFuioavNbcOWdcBGv3Yx2ihoVbOseQlnwVW8%253D%26st%3D2019-01-10T05%253A34%253A41Z%26se%3D2021-01-10T05%253A39%253A41Z%26sp%3Drw&demoConfig=eyJlbmFibGVTdHJlYW1pbmciOnRydWUsImF1dG9SZWNvdmVyRXJyb3IiOnRydWUsImVuYWJsZVdvcmtlciI6dHJ1ZSwiZHVtcGZNUDQiOmZhbHNlLCJsZXZlbENhcHBpbmciOi0xLCJsaW1pdE1ldHJpY3MiOi0xLCJ3aWRldmluZUxpY2Vuc2VVcmwiOiIifQ==)

Comment: try just the first segment - up to but not include the first 'discontinuity'... will it play .. if not take just that segment , removing all query strings from the end of your SAS urls...  will it play ?   in genl, with hls on chrome, if u are very careful with the spec, it  plays..   try chrome mobile where video.js not required for hls.

Comment: No difference, kinda loads, then buffer stalled or buffer append errors and player breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating FFMPEG to 20190122-87c165c nightly build fixed the issue for me. The stream plays seamlessly now. Whoever knows what changed in this build, feel free to add more info.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW - similar to your stack, here is [media_file](https://warm-earth-97740.herokuapp.com/parse/files/dDgpCbCGWqIojuPcym19Ov6vEkmBH8Nk90P310.m3u8) with corresponding m3u8 that is the result of similar concatenation with "DISCONTINUITY" directives between chuncks ... it plays on the following:

chrome desktop with plug-in to plays hls
chrome mobile native 
safari mobile native

NOTE during testing , it helped to pay very close attention to the hls spec and chrome mobile did play the m3u8 files that followed the spec.

```
curl -v https://warm-earth-97740.herokuapp.com/parse/files/dDgpCbCGWqIojuPcym19Ov6vEkmBH8Nk90P310.m3u8


*   Trying 52.4.86.246...
* Connected to warm-earth-97740.herokuapp.com (52.4.86.246) port 443 (#0)
* found 148 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 597 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ECDHE_RSA_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*    server certificate verification OK
*    compression: NULL
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
> GET /parse/files/dDgpCbCGWqIojuPcym19Ov6vEkmBH8Nk90P3qovv/eaec53eca49d3876e4d0546d5ba4b3d0_newMovie_10.m3u8 HTTP/1.1
> Host: warm-earth-97740.herokuapp.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Cowboy
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Parse-Master-Key, X-Parse-REST-API-Key, X-Parse-Javascript-Key, X-Parse-Application-Id, X-Parse-Client-Version, X-Parse-Session-Token, X-Requested-With, X-Parse-Revocable-Session, Content-Type
< Content-Type: application/vnd.apple.mpegurl
< Content-Length: 2566
< Date: Fri, 11 Jan 2019 19:14:55 GMT
< Via: 1.1 vegur
< 
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:5
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXTINF:4.800000,
1b0090f29fb79caa2cda29c4a9405250_segment_000.ts
#EXTINF:4.800000,
e93ecb8e2fd64c2423b9744701437db8_segment_001.ts
#EXTINF:4.800000,
642133a4b14827f290b7a309bb803fef_segment_002.ts
#EXTINF:0.600000,
0586ff030f8eb689960623c0ac98b8ab_segment_003.ts
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXTINF:4.800000,
cb4c289e9c2832fa7227a3ad270d481e_segment_000.ts
#EXTINF:4.800000,
0e90596f820f2392ce3de6c3fed03829_segment_001.ts
#EXTINF:4.800000,
d11bd4e1d0ace74eaa94600b921feb6f_segment_002.ts
#EXTINF:0.400000,
8566c774725c9c607a5629a095d770df_segment_003.ts
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXTINF:4.800000,
bf7e10c3d50a189940dabe72ef732d0b_segment_000.ts
#EXTINF:4.800000,
758552f634ce20946483437f17359823_segment_001.ts
#EXTINF:4.800000,
3f0c7f1cea905a924eb242981a411282_segment_002.ts
#EXTINF:0.400000,
cd16b3ebd53b3bd88cbed12f2fc0b33d_segment_003.ts
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXTINF:4.800000,
d2bec0e6d46f5b1fda347343d8057011_segment_000.ts
#EXTINF:4.800000,
04e696210cf6972c95200c01d50b01f3_segment_001.ts
#EXTINF:4.200000,
55c4957fe7f038efe38afc356395e567_segment_002.ts
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXTINF:4.800000,
f5b9206e21ee83d9b8fc2c4d610351f5_segment_000.ts
#EXTINF:4.800000,
778735b8d827e5355d841f61f984df73_segment_001.ts
#EXTINF:4.800000,
9dd73db85aede3b22b542e9efb02d745_segment_002.ts
#EXTINF:1.400000,
97f123c5e2cc9b2125e11ca8c9d2f3a8_segment_003.ts
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXTINF:4.800000,
6b3275bd1197f5c3eba3e6f0b3f19126_segment_000.ts
#EXTINF:4.800000,
2371b54d8d8d038b86c503a3871ac74e_segment_001.ts
#EXTINF:4.800000,
f774171a7f7b82881db261f4237a1b6e_segment_002.ts
#EXTINF:0.400000,
65807b83e64381d7352f259787f204b1_segment_003.ts
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXTINF:4.800000,
8e6bbaae596b47e05029d4e2a9d0d930_segment_000.ts
#EXTINF:4.800000,
13de0dbe95396c9c52047e5476bdb6e1_segment_001.ts
#EXTINF:4.800000,
97be7120a8ccf2a2fc3a92dc3f5ad20d_segment_002.ts
#EXTINF:0.600000,
15d94e0b89ad3e2f7c04713b147c6964_segment_003.ts
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXTINF:4.800000,
5b262a770de6d0045ccbb764951b5c5b_segment_000.ts
#EXTINF:4.800000,
3a8c5901a2a81ab77a567b701a156630_segment_001.ts
#EXTINF:4.800000,
8b881d13554a789b9709a3f32229258b_segment_002.ts
#EXTINF:0.600000,
f161f6ba0ad5b191cf10e7e1be5998ca_segment_003.ts
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXTINF:4.800000,
b064f7b34a2a968cc5f8cea50be392e9_segment_000.ts
#EXTINF:4.800000,
0d76365156e04b61f475db3d59421c64_segment_001.ts
#EXTINF:4.800000,
9449e3f7b468277524d053ff4aae416d_segment_002.ts
#EXTINF:2.400000,
70ba88bf8b428cdb783f8f955e51f8a9_segment_003.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
* Connection #0 to host warm-earth-97740.herokuapp.com left intact
```

Comment: There is a major difference here that I'm not sure plays a role in it working or not. I'm using FMP4, as well as range headers. I see your playlist is also VOD, not live, while mine is an event playlist. I tried to implement all these according to spec though.

Comment: I tried to convert my playlist to use TS files, and it didn't play at all in any player.